# Как в конструктор класса протащить базовый класс

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть класс:

```
class signal:
    lst = []
    booklist = None
    data = [[0,  'nickname' , "nickname"],
            [1,  'name'     , "notempty"]]

    def __init__(self, row, nrow):
        for key in self.data:
            if signal.check(row[key[0]], key[2], "Лист: " + self.booklist + " Строка: " + str(nrow)):
                setattr(self, key[1], row[key[0]])
```

Объекты класса хочу хранить в списке lst.
Для чего создаю их таким образом в основном теле программы:

```
signal.lst.append(signal(row, rownum))
```

Что как то немного режет глаз.
Поэтому, хочу при создании объекта, сохранять его в lst сразу в конструкторе.

Пробовал использовать декоратор

```
@classmethod
def __init__(cls, self, row, nrow):
...
   cls.lst.append(self)
```

А в основном теле программы:

```
signal(row, rownum)
```

Тогда интерпретатор меня ругал так:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nrow'
```

Есть какое-нибудь изящное решение?

Comment: А если бы, было написано не `signal(row, rownum)` а `signal(row, nrow)`, тогда тоже ругался бы?

Comment: да, тоже бы ругался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ссылаться на lst через self
    self.lst.append(self)

должно работать. Cобственно следующий код

```
class Signal:
lst = []
booklist = None
data = [[0,  'nickname' , "nickname"],
        [1,  'name'     , "notempty"]]

    def __init__(self, row, nrow):
        for key in self.data:
            setattr(self, key[1], row[key[0]])
        self.lst.append(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Signal([1, 2], ['name'])
    print(s.lst)
    s2 = Signal([2, 5], ['nickname'])
    print(s.lst)
    print(s2.lst)
    print(s.lst == s2.lst, s.lst is s2.lst)
```

Выдает

```
[<__main__.Signal object at 0x000000616773D080>]
[<__main__.Signal object at 0x000000616773D080>, <__main__.Signal object at 0x000000616773D128>]
[<__main__.Signal object at 0x000000616773D080>, <__main__.Signal object at 0x000000616773D128>]
True True
```

Что соответствует ожидаемому.

Comment: Хмм, не думал, что у объекта есть доступ к статическому свойству класса.